# How to replace true with false in column where ever the corresponding column has null in it using PYspark?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, replace, null

I am new to pyspark, I have an issue with Naan values. So, I have a data frame like below:

```
df =
 name  std output
0 er   1st False
1 rt   2nd False
2 Naan 4th True 
3 Naan 8th True
4 Naan 10th True
5 fg   Naan False
6 Naan Naan True
```

Now, whenever the column name has naan it reflects True. I want to replace True with false where ever the column name has null values in it. I want to know how to do in `PYSPARK`

Execpted Output:

```
df =
 name  std output
0 er   1st False
1 rt   2nd False
2 Naan 4th False
3 Naan 8th False
4 Naan 10th False
5 fg   Naan False
6 Naan Naan False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `when + otherwise` statements.

**`Example:`**

```
df.show()

#+----+---+------+
#|name|std|output|
#+----+---+------+
#|  er|1st| false|
#|Naan|4th|  true|
#+----+---+------+

from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn('output',when((col('name')=='Naan') & (col('output')),False).otherwise(col('output'))).show()

#+----+---+------+
#|name|std|output|
#+----+---+------+
#|  er|1st| false|
#|Naan|4th| false|
#+----+---+------+
```